# Eclips-pmd requires eclipse runs on a JVM version 11 or later

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jvm, pmd

I installed the plugin and when I tried to add to my project, I got the following message:
eclipse-pmd requires that Eclipse runs on a JVM with version 11 or later but it currently runs on a JVM with version 1.8.0_201

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Get a Java 11 or higher JDK or JRE (e.g. from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)) and make sure [Eclipse is run with it](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Comment: I was able to do that, thank you, now I'm having an issue importing the ruleset into PMD, can you help ?

Comment: Best to make a new question for that question, rather than wait for someone to say they can respond to it in this one.

Comment: Yes, as ntlind has already said, please ask this as a separate question with more details and a link to the PMD plug-in you use ([there are several](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/pmd)).